# Only getting mirrorred display, not extended, when offloading from Nvidia to Intel iGPU with RandR

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, xrandr

I've got a GTX-580 and an iGPU (i7-2600k). I'm wanting two displays from the NVIDIA and one from the Intel.

In both 16.04 and 16.10 I've tried:

- Current Intel driver from repo, latest Intel driver from Intel's Update Tool, modesetting driver only. The Intel driver seems to have no effect on anything.
- Nvidia 304, 340, 367 and 375. Still only mirrored.
- Default & latest Nouveau drivers - work great on 16.10 (not at all on 16.04). Well, apart from the cursor flickering/disappearing on the Nvidia outputs and making those monitors pretty much unusable.

In 16.04 Nouveau had the screen 'working' in so far as I could drag windows onto it, the monitor powered up, and I could see all 3 screens in the display manager. There was no output though. In 16.10 it works so close to perfectly, right from the installation screen, that it's maddening - but there's that damned transient cursor.

Following the [offloading instructions](http://uk.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/319.12/README/randr14.html) from Nvidia I can get the third monitor to *mirror* the primary, but I cannot get it to *extend*. I've tried manually setting monitor positioning in xrandr with the same result. Only the displays connected to the Nvidia GPU show up in the X session Nvidia settings, nothing from the Intel; all 3 show up in the Display Manager and Arandr.

Those instructions are completely unclear on whether I should be expecting a mirrored output or an extended one. Maybe a mirrored output is exactly what I should be expecting and I'm not setting up the X screens properly. 
I'm wondering if I need to set up a virtual screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, fixed it. As far as I can tell, extending a display (at least on my 580) requires use of the `nvidiaXineramaInfoOverride` option. I couldn't find any docs for this option in the relevant RandR sections of Nvidia's driver READMEs, or really anywhere - I came across it on the Arch forums.

Using this display setup, going left to right:

Nvidia : HDMI-0 : 1920x1080
Nvidia : DVI-I-2 : 1280x1024
Intel : HDMI-1-2 : 1280x1024

In Ubuntu 16.x xorg config files are located in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`, with the filename being `whateverYouWant.conf`.

Here's the entirety of mine, based on the Nvidia [sample](http://uk.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/319.12/README/randr14.html), but with unnecessary sections removed and the `nvidiaXineramaInfoOverride` option added:

> Section "Screen"
>       Identifier "nvidia"
>       Device "nvidia"
>       Option "nvidiaXineramaInfoOverride" "1920x1080+0+0, 1280x1024+1920+0, 1280x1024+3200+0"
>   EndSection
>
> Section "Device"
>       Identifier "nvidia"
>       Driver "nvidia"
>   EndSection
>
> Section "Device"
>       Identifier "intel"
>       Driver "modesetting"
>   EndSection

Note the numbers by the "nvidiaXineramaInfoOverride" option. The number after the first '+' is for the width offset. Modify them so they're equivalent to the sum of the widths of the previous displays.

Finally, to start up the third monitor:

> xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 1 0
>   xrandr --output HDMI-1-2 --right-of DVI-I-2 --mode 1280x1024